# NSString from enum value

Tags: cocoa, object, enums

Is it possible to get a `NSString` of the value of `kIconServices128PixelDataARGB`, meaning: `@"ic07"`?

```
enum {
    kIconServices16PixelDataARGB  = 'ic04', /* uses kSmall32BitIconIndex and kSmallDeepMaskIconIndex*/
    kIconServices32PixelDataARGB  = 'ic05', /* uses kLarge32BitIconIndex and kLargeDeepMaskIconIndex*/
    kIconServices48PixelDataARGB  = 'ic06', /* uses kHuge32BitIconIndex and kHugeDeepMaskIconIndex*/
    kIconServices128PixelDataARGB = 'ic07' /* uses kThumbnailDataIndex and kThumbnailMaskIndex*/
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are APIs that make this conversion simpler, e.g. `UTCreateStringForOSType()` returning `CFStringRef` (which you can just cast to `NSString*` as they're equivalent), or in QTKit there's `QTStringForOSType()`.